# How to test a Lawn Mower's brushless DC motor

Tags: lawn-mower, motor

I inherited a Ryobi 18V 16" lawn mower (P1100) from the previous house owners and am trying to diagnose why it won't spin.

The motor is brushless with 3 leads. I spin it with a drill and put an amp meter across each pair of wires in turn (3 combinations). Two read about 0.5 amps and one 0 amps. Does that mean one winding is bad? I thought so but I ordered another motor off eBay and that one reads the same -- the same pair reads 0 amps.

Now I wonder if I am just performing an invalid test or if the same winding is coincidentally bad on the eBay motor.  Anyone know if this is a valid way to test a brushless motor? Can I return the eBay motor as definitely DOA?

--BobG

Comment: *A* brushless motor yes, *your* brushless motor perhaps not. does your motor have built-in ESC?

Comment: With a mower, I'd start by triple-checking the protective defeat-owner-cutting-self circuitry.